# android spinner and array adapter programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to programmatically create a Spinner using an ArrayAdapter. This is being done in a closed source jar as part of an Android library project and I do not have any access to resources.

I want to know how to customize the layout and the text view that displays the spinner.

--EDIT--
Presently I am using the following code

```
ArrayAdapter<T> spinnerData = new ArrayAdapter<T>(this, Android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, T[]);

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerData);
```

What is happening is that I cannot control the size of the fonts, colours or anything else. When I click on the spinner to select something all the options are in really small text. I want to be able to change the way it renders on screen.

Comment: will you please be more clear..???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just create a custom ArrayAdapter and define how the spinner textview should look in that getDropDownView method of the adapter

```
public class CustomizedSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

 private Activity context;
 String[] data = null;

 public CustomizedSpinnerAdapter(Activity context, int resource, String[] data2)
 {
     super(context, resource, data2);
     this.context = context;
     this.data = data2;
 }
  ...

 @Override
 public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {   
     View row = convertView;
     if(row == null)
     {
         //inflate your customlayout for the textview
         LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
         row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, parent, false);
     }
     //put the data in it
     String item = data[position];
     if(item != null)
     {   
        TextView text1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text1.setText(item);
     }

     return row;
 }
...
}
```

and set this adapter for the spinner

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
final String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.data);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new CustomizedSpinnerAdapter(
            AddSlaveActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            data);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Are their any "good-looking" defaults that I can use?

Comment: you can take anything from /platforms/android-13/data/res/drawable-hdpi from the android folder jst to check with

Comment: I cannot use resources because the activity displaying the spinner is in a closed source jar in an android library project. Are there any views/layouts in the android.R class that I can use.